# Android: Starting intent service within fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, intentservice

I have multiple fragments within an activity. Every fragment has to display some data that is fetched from the server using REST. I have been implementing `IntentService` with a corresponding receiver for REST requests. Right now I am able to do this by making fragments as inner class within the activity.

The problem I have with inner class is, on orientation change, an error is thrown like "cannot instantiate fragment, no empty constructor". For this problem, on search I found answers like either make the inner class static or create a standalone public class for Fragment. I still don't understand why would this happen on orientation change.

Now if I take the approach of creating a separate standalone class for Fragment, I will have to pass the activity object around to do `startService` and `registerReceiver`. And I do not want to use `AsyncTask` for this, as in my app I perform multiple REST requests within a single fragment and `IntentService` allows a broadcast to be sent after every request so that I do not have to wait until all the requests are finished to start loading the screen. And I feel it is not ok to pass activity object to a fragment. Shouldn't the fragment be as loosely coupled as possible with the activity so that same fragment can be used within multiple activities? If yes, what would be the best approach in resolving this?

Comment: fragment.getActivity() holds an instance to the Actvity hosting the fragment so you shouldn't be passing it around. Also, startService & registerReceiver come from the abstract interface Context. You are not coupling them.